# I automated the process to search an item in Amazon. However I cannot add the item to cart. ElementNotFound Exception is being raised. Any tips?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, checkout

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

global browser 
browser= webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.google.com") 
wait = WebDriverWait(browser,45)
search = browser.find_element(By.NAME,"q") 
search.send_keys("Amazon")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) 
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,"amazon.in"))).click()
search = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"twotabsearchtextbox"))) 
search.send_keys("PS5") 
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT,"Sony PS5 PlayStation Console"))).click()
try:
add_to_cart_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="add-to-cart-button"]')))
add_to_cart_button.click()
except Exception as e:
print("Error:", e)
finally:
browser.quit()

time.sleep(2)
browser.quit()
```

'''I did try Explicit Time to search for an element, as it gives the time to locate the element. I started to use the XPATH too but it doesn't work in any way. Everything goes good when it comes to add to cart button the web driver can't find the element.'''

Comment: What is `amazon.in` locator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get element, because line

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT,"Sony PS5 PlayStation Console"))).click()
```

opens new tab.

`Selenium` doesn't automatically switch contexts, so you should switch context to new tab after click.

```py
#previous code
window_handles = browser.window_handles
new_window_handle = window_handles[-1]
browser.switch_to.window(new_window_handle)
add_to_cart_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'add-to-cart-button')))
add_to_cart_button.click()
```

Btw, you can access direct amazon link and not to search it in Google.

Comment: Yeah thanks for your suggestion. However, as you said I have directed the link to the amazon and add-to-card button then the code works fine. But when the code is long as I mentioned above it couldn't find the add to cart element. I wanted to try to execute it in many ways for my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Problems you need to fix:

1. You have locator problem It is `add-to-cart-button-ubb`, not `add-to-cart-button`
2. You have to wait until your button is clickable, not just present on the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver")
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 45)
search = browser.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
search.send_keys("Amazon")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "amazon.ca"))).click()
search = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "twotabsearchtextbox")))
search.send_keys("Sony PS5 PlayStation Console")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@data-component-type, 's-search-result')][4]//a[text()='PlayStation 5']"))
).click()

try:
    add_to_cart_button = wait.until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="add-to-cart-button-ubb"]'))
    )
    add_to_cart_button.click()
    print("Success!")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", e)
finally:
    browser.quit()

browser.quit()
```

Notes:

- In my answer I go to google.ca. Change to your domain
- I look to a console by search "Sony PS5 PlayStation Console", as in Canada results are different and you cannot predict them.
- Check indentation in your code
- I use local executable for `chromedriver`. You can use a different approach.
- Also, when there is an id, you can use it without XPATH. Instead of  `add_to_cart_button = wait.until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="add-to-cart-button-ubb"]')) )` you can do `add_to_cart_button = wait.until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'add-to-cart-button-ubb"')) )`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I will let you know the status of my code.

Comment: It doesn't work bro

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Same the driver cannot locate the add-to-cart element. I have tried the "add-to-cart-ubb" id but the webpages have different id's and XPATH's for different country webpages.